# How can I get the pixel color of an image at the current pointer position in a universal app with C#?

Tags: c#, colors, win-universal-app, pixel

I want to get the Pixel Color of an Image at the current pointer/mouse position in a universal app with C#. As the Bitmap Class does not work anymore, all the hints I found, were useless. The purpose of this is to program a color picker.

Comment: Could use a bit more of what you did find and why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Using an image that's a resource in the project, this seems to work (using [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx))

```
WriteableBitmap wb;

private async void ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    wb = await BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromContent(((sender as Image).Source as BitmapImage).UriSource);
}

private async void ImageTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pos = e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement);

    var px = wb.GetPixel((int)pos.X, (int)pos.Y);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"R: {px.R} G: {px.G} B: {px.B} ");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I already had tried the WriteableBitmap class, but Visual Studio 2015 marked the GetPixel method as not defined. In the Microsoft documentation I didn't find it either. Your remark (using WirteableBitmapEx) was very helpful. Now I have installed the WirteableBitmapEx package and the method is available.

Comment: WriteableBitmapEx not WirteableBitmapEx .

Comment: @Lacey If I use  BitmapImage.SetSource from a stream so I cant use the UriSource.How can I convert BitmapImage to writeableBitmap?

Comment: Thx @Lacey .I've been found it for 10 days.